# SQL - Stored Procedures for reporting using Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using Reporting Service in a ASP.NET MVC4 project (using Visual Studio 2010) to generate reports and I'm working with stored procedures. I have a table **Product** which can belong to persons. That's the concept of allocation. A product can be allocated to different persons (many-to-many relation) and I have an intermediate table between those two :

[image: Allocations tables]

The thing I want tot do in my report is to display the information related to each existing product including the owner. In this situation, I can have 2 types of owners : the company (so the product **has never been allocated** or the **last allocation** has an EndDate) or a person (so the last allocation doesn't have an EndDate or has a "future" EndDate).

I know that all these verifications should be made in my report template but for the SQL stored procedure, I have no idea about how to do to get the last allocation for each product (if there is any).

Any idea which could help is welcomed.

EDIT : Updated query

```
SELECT pr.SerialNumber, coalesce (p.LastName, 'US') as Owner
FROM bm_Products pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (Select Id_Person, Id_Product, max(ISNULL(EndDate,getdate()+1)) as MaxAllocDate
    FROM bm_ProductAllocations a
    WHERE EndDate > getdate()
    group by Id_Person, Id_Product
    having max(ISNULL(EndDate, getdate()+1)) = 
        (select max(isnull(EndDate, getdate()+1))
        from bm_ProductAllocations where Id_Product = a.Id_Product)
    ) pa on pr.Id_Product = pa.Id_Product
LEFT OUTER JOIN bm_Persons p on pa.Id_Person = p.Id_Person
```

The result :

```
SerialNumber                                       Owner                                              
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- 
78745148154815204                                  US                                                 
84512048150410522                                  US                                                 
84512841520415205                                  US                                                 
87451284512485120                                  US                                                 
56123051215215215                                  US                                                 
48512485487487856                                  US                                                 
CNU1510ZL0                                         US                                                 
8456656551521                                      US                                                 
4154854854151                                      US                                                 
4851205230047                                      US                                                 
4511120521050                                      US                                                 
84515151320541201                                  US                                                 
74161230326524165                                  US
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see "company" for owner on the table shown, so i'll assume for now that it is in the products table, a hardcoded 'US' because you own it, or you can provide an update.

```
SELECT pr.Product, coalesce (p.person, 'US') as Owner
FROM Product pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (Select id_person, id_product, max(ISNULL(EndDate,getdate()+1)) as MaxAllocDate
    FROM Product_Allocation a
    WHERE Enddate > getdate()
    group by id_person, id_product
    having max(ISNULL(EndDate, getdate()+1)) = 
        (select max(isnull(Enddate, getdate()+1))
        from product_allocation where id_product = a.id_Product)
    ) pa on pr.id_product = pa.id_product
LEFT OUTER JOIN person p on pa.id_person = p.id_person
```

The subquery will give you the max end date by product and person.  since we need the subquery to return the person, you would possibly get multiple id_person records for each product if you have multiple allocations that haven't expired.  The "having" clause will use the already aggregated end date to match to the max end date by product without the person, so you will get only the "most future" allocation end date.  Since the product allocation is joined to the person, and they are left joined to the product table, if there are no unexpired or future allocations, or there are no allocations at all, then you will get 'US' as your owner.  you can always add in another table join directly from product if your "company" is somewhere else, and substitute that for 'US'.

I don't have a data set to work off of that exactly duplicates this, so I can't test it, but I did test the having process and it functioned correctly.

if there are other assumption like, only one allocation at a time, etc, this could be simplified.  Also you could work this through a memory table with only current and future allocations by product, but I believe this should work.  You may need to adjust the 'getdate()' if you are working off date only not date time.  If that's the case then use cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101) as datetime) and return only the date portion of the getdate function.

Hope this helps you out

Comment: Thanks for your help. In fact, in my database, all my tables are starting by "bm_" so I tried to adapt your query to my needs. Anyway, I got an error when I wanted to test to execute it : No column name was specified for column 3 of 'pa'. Do you have an idea? Thanks again !

Comment: Subqueries must have field names for all fields.  I forgot to alias the max allocation date. edited above.  Let me know how this works out for you

Comment: Thanks for your modification, now the query can be executed without problem. Anyway, for all my products, I got "US" as Owner which means the product have no allocation or the last allocation is finished... Edited to let you know what I've got. Thanks again !